# Create a function for saving tables

Tags: r, save, tidyverse, fwrite

I need to save a number of tables, in the same way, using the [fwrite](/questions/tagged/fwrite) function.

I have tried the below.

FYI: `group_name` is a character object of length 1 (should just print "group_one", for example).

```
# Save table
save_table <- function(x) {
  table_name <- as.character(x)
  fwrite(
    x, 
    file = 
      paste0(
        "tables/", 
        group_name, 
        "/",
        table_name,
        ".csv"
      )
  )
}
```

I get the following error message:

> ```
>  Error in fwrite(x, file = paste0("tables/", group_name, "/",  : 
>   is.character(file) && length(file) == 1L && !is.na(file) is not TRUE
> ```

Comment: What exactly are you passing in to this function? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by replacing the 'as.character' with 'deparse(substitute(x))'.

```
save_table <- function(x) {
  table_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  fwrite(
    x, 
    file = 
      paste0(
        "tables/", 
        group_name, 
        "/",
        table_name,
        ".csv"
      )
  )
}
```